# Can't get equal width columns with GridBagLayout layout manager

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I'm having an issue with GridBagLayout() and having even column widths. Essentially, I'm adding three buttons to a panel with a GridBagLayout lahyout manager. I expect (want) the widths of the buttons to be the same, and to fill the cell they are in. However, because the buttons are of different sizes (dependent on the text in them), I end up having buttons of different sizes. Below is the code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;


public class ShitHeadGUI extends JPanel {

    public String[] s = new String[] {"Ace of Hearts", "2 of Diamonds", "3 of Clubs"};


    //JPanel pile = new JPanel();
    List<JPanel> hands = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
    GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shithead");

    public ShitHeadGUI() {
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

        cons.gridx = 0;
        cons.gridy = 0;
        cons.weightx = 1;
        cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            hands.add(new JPanel());
            hands.get(i).setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            this.add(hands.get(i));
            cons.gridy++;
        }

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();   

        addCards(null);
    }

    public void addCards(Hand h) {

        List<JButton> btnCard = new ArrayList<JButton>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {//h.size(); i++) {
            cons.gridx = i;
            //btnCard.add(new JButton(h.getCard(i).toString()));
            btnCard.add(new JButton(s[i]));
            hands.get(0).add(btnCard.get(i), cons);
        }       
    }
}
```

The "Ace of Hearts" is a little different than the "2 of Diamonds" size and the "3 of clubs" is noticeably smaller. I want them all to be equal size. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: GridBagLayout will *never* make all columns the same width.  GridBagLayout cells are flexible;  their size always depends on their contents.  No GridBagConstraints value can change this behavior.  As Aubin said, use a GridLayout instead of a GridBagLayout.  Or, if you want a challenge, use SpringLayout.

Comment: The number of buttons change

Comment: My proposal: Find out what the longest possible card name string is. Use this value as a static final for comparison. Write a method to which you pass every card name before adding it to the button. The method is supposed to check the length. If the length of the name is lower than the maximum, let the method add whitespaces and then return the "corrected" String. Add it to the button. It's a little hacky but a makable way that solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a little hack... Set preferred size of all components to some stupid small size like for example:

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2, 2));
```

and add this:

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx = 1.0; // fill all available space horizontally
c.weighty = 1.0; // fill all available space vertically
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the method I was talking about in my comment. This should help you to use GridBagLayout with buttons of exactly the same length.

What you can't fix is the fact, that the text will never be perfectly centered if the length's difference is an odd number. Then the right side will always get one whitespace more than the left...

```
public class StringExtender {

    static final int maxCardNameLength = "Queen of Diamonds".length();


    public static void main (String args[]) {

        System.out.println(StringExtender.extend("2 of Spades").length());
        System.out.println(StringExtender.extend("Jack of Clubs").length());
        System.out.println(StringExtender.extend("King of Diamonds").length());
        System.out.println(StringExtender.extend("Queen of Diamonds").length());

    }

    // 
    static String extend(String cardName) {

        int diff = maxCardNameLength - cardName.length();
        int diffHalf = 0;
        String result = cardName;

        // is the String shorter than maximum?
        if(diff > 0) {
            // is the difference greater than 1?
            // if true, then always pad left and right
            if(diff > 1 ){
                diffHalf = diff/2;

                // add padding left
                String paddingLeft = "%" + (result.length() + diffHalf) + "s";
                result = String.format(paddingLeft, result);
                System.out.println("Result: |" + result + "|");
            }

            // add padding right
            String paddingRight = "%-" + (maxCardNameLength) + "s";
            result = String.format(paddingRight, result);
            System.out.println("Result: |" + result + "|");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up simply replacing GridBagLayout with GridLayout.